# Can I extend Traefik in a way to open the request header check user identity and update request url?

Tags: traefik, api-gateway

I want to add a sort of custom middleware in Traefik, where I can check user identity and after validating from the database, I want to route users to different versions of the application? Is it possible with Traefik?

Answer (score 2):

For the time being, the only way to add a custom middleware to Traefik is to fork it and add your custom middleware into the source code and build it for yourself. Actually this is not too difficult but of course it comes with all the downsides of forking. There is an example here: https://github.com/negasus/traefik2-luascript. You need to edit it a bit because it is somewhat outdated but I was able to add my custom middleware by following it.